# #include <QGL> QGL: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, linux-mint, c++, qt

I've got a problem my dudes.

For a school project, I must install some stuff to use a graphics library in c++. The lib is called [libQGLViewer](http://libqglviewer.com/). I'm using Linux Mint.

The problem is the following: When installing the lib, there's a sample project to try our configuration. I tried to run it by using

```
qmake
make   <-- Problem here
sudo make install
```

When I'm using "make" an error appears:

```
fatal error: QGL: No such file or directory
```

because of a line in the code :

```
#include <QGL>
```

So ... I guess the problem comes from the qt5 library I have to install to use the libQGLViewer. I tried some stuff like reinstalling qt5, modifying some things. But nothing worked and nothing exists on the Internet about the problem.

Do you have any idea on how to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install also the developer version of the library. The library contain just the binary version, so just to execute programs that need it. The developers version includes other files, needed e.g. to compiler programs that need such library.

In your case, the package should be something like: `libqt5opengl5-dev`.

Note: Often it is required to execute also a `./configure`, which will help to find such library (after you install it). Not sure if such search it is included into your `qmake` step.